# Anyway to stop an "onmousemove" function while mouse is still in the movement area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a small game where the user draws straight lines on a canvas with the mouse (using onmousedown and onmouseup as the events of start and finish). What I am trying to do is to use onmousedown and onmousemove to create a preview of that line to guide the user. Problem is, after the user releases the mouse button, "onmousemove" still creates previews from the point where the user released the mouse.

I've tried using a return 0 or a while(ok) (I'm new to JavaScript), but none of it worked.
Is there a possibility to ditch onmousemove entirely and use some kind of timer (like in C#)?

HTML

```
$(document.getElementById("myCanvas")).on("mousedown",function()
{
    startline();
});         

$(document.getElementById("myCanvas")).on("mouseup",function()
{
    endline();
});
```

Script

```
function startline ()
{
    oldx = event.pageX; // globally declared
    oldy = event.pageY;
    $(document.getElementById("myCanvas")).on("mousemove",function()
    {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
        livex = event.pageX;
        livey = event.pageY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#808080";
        ctx.moveTo(vechix, vechiy);
        ctx.lineTo(livex, livey);
        ctx.stroke();
    }); 
}
function endline ()
{
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.moveTo(oldx, oldy);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

I expect for the onmousemove function to stop when mouse is released.
Also, the output creates a thousand lines and displays them all, but I've managed to solve that.

Comment: When you get an `mouseup` event, `off()` the `mousemove` event listener to remove it. [Off](https://api.jquery.com/off)

Comment: See: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding $(document.getElementById("myCanvas")).off("mousemove");  in the "mouseup" event listener completely solved my problem.

Comment: No need to write `document.getElementById` inside `$()` ... can simplify to `$('#myCanvas')`